# segfault after setting field in objc

Tags: objective-c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a simple program using Objective-C without using Foundation, Cocoa or GNUStep as a challenge to see if it's possible to do so at all and I've run into an odd problem.

Here's the code:

writer.h:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <stdio.h>
@interface Writer // no superclass, because there is none
@property char* value;
+ (id) alloc;
- (id) initWithValue: (char*) val;
- (void) free;
- (void) hello;
- (void) printText;
@end
```

writer.m:

```
#import "writer.h"
@implementation Writer
@synthesize value;

+ (id) alloc {
  return class_createInstance(self, 0);
}

- (id) initWithValue: (char*) val {
  if(self) {
    printf("setting val to %s\n", val);
    value = val;
    printf("_val is %s\n", value);
    return self;
  }
  else return nil;
}

- (void) free {
  puts("disposing object");
  object_dispose(self);
}

- (void) printText {
  puts("printing value");
  puts(value);
}

- (void) hello {
  puts("Hi there");
}
@end
```

main.m:

```
#import "writer.h"
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  Writer *w = [Writer alloc];

  puts("calling hello");
  [w hello];

  puts("setting value");
  [w setValue: "Hello, world"];

  puts("calling hello again");
  [w hello]; // segfault

  puts("calling printText");
  [w printText];

  puts("calling free");
  [w free];
  return 0;
}
```

When I then run `gcc *m -o test -lobjc; ./test` I get the following output:

```
calling hello
Hi there
setting value
calling hello again
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So why is it that the object receives messages just fine before I set the field, but segfaults after? Note that it's the exact same result when using `initWithValue`, doing it this way is just easier to debug.

Edit: I also want to point out that I also tried with a private local variable instead of the `@property`, it still gave me a segfault

As per yate's request here's the output of gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/ElectricCoffee/Desktop/test/test 
calling hello
Hi there
setting value
calling hello again

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff8ed760a3 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8ed760a3 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000100000be3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffb28) at main.m:13
```

Comment: This is **the wrong** way to create, use and delete objects. Make it a subclass of `NSObject` and don't try to be smarter than Apple's developers, because you aren't. Instead, google a decent Objective-C tutorial and familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of the language and good practices therein.

Comment: Ask any experienced Objective-C developer about your code. Each of them will say that this is a wrong way to use the language.

Comment: you mean "any experienced apple developer" since objc is primarily used on apple devices, which is a shame considering how much potential it has

Comment: You interpret it in any way it pleases you. If you think that "experienced Objective-C developer" means "experienced Apple developer", then go ahead.

Comment: no, I am downvoting it based on its content.

Comment: it's a valid memory allocation related question regarding the inner workings of objective-c there's nothing objectively wrong in it. Objective-C is a language, not a set of libraries, and it should be treated as such.

Comment: Where exactly does `setValue` come from, is that suppose to be a method in `Writer`?  Never used Objective C...

Comment: @yate `setValue:` is an automatically generated method that comes from synthesising a variable. when I write `@synthesize value;` it generates a getter method called `value` and a setter method called `setValue:`, it saves me manually writing accessors and mutators for private local fields

Comment: Can you compile `gcc` with the `-g`, run it in `gdb`, and give the output when it segfaults.  Maybe provide the output of `bt` in `gdb` also

Comment: could you give an example to help me along? I've mostly relied on IDEs and I'm not super familiar with gcc flags other than -o and -lobjc

Comment: `gcc -g *m -o test -lobjc`  `gdb ./test` (now in gdb) `run` (should segfault and provide more details for you to copy)   `bt`   (should provide a stacktrace for you to copy)

Comment: Is `puts()` buffered? Is it possible you're segfaulting on `printText` (that would make a lot more sense), but the console output is out of order? (Side note: `if(self)` in `initWithValue:` is nonsense -- you'd never get into the method if you sent a message to `nil`.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I added `if(self)` because the normal way of doing init is `if(self = [super init])` but since I don't have a super class, I figured I'd just leave the if anyway, in case I ever get one

Comment: @yate I have now added the gbt log as requested

Comment: It looks like what John says is right, it's segfaulting after calling the method on line 13 of main, which is `printText`. The line which is causing the actual segfault is `puts(value)`.  This is because `value` has not been initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes a difference, but are you linking against GNU's libobjc, or Apple's?

Comment: @yate which is weird, 'cause if I use `initWithValue:` I can see it DOES in fact write the variable from the output of "printf("_val is %s\n", value);" but why is it that it segfaults when I call a method that doesn't use the value, but instead just prints a string directly? I mean it's not trying to access the variable

Comment: @JoshCaswell I have no idea actually, how would I check?

Comment: Adding `-Wl,-t` to your compiler invocation should print out the various things that the linker loads.

Answer (score 0):

Adding { Class isa; }

You'll overwrite the missing isa if you don't have one.

"and anyone who writes ‘no superclass because there isn’t one’ is a terrible programmer." -- Sorry for this line, I just have to make it at least 30 characters.

Comment: _I just have to make it at least 30 characters_. So, make a comment instead.

Comment: Should an obvious answer be considered as a comment?

Comment: And someone just have to vote the only valid answer down without providing anything better! Awesome!

Comment: Since 2 persons upvote your comment, I want to point out that 1) It's Stackoverflow's suggestion that you should avoid answering questions in comments especially when there are 14 comments already on-going. 2) I cannot even add comment due to my first-time-posting reputation. So those voters are voting with terrible judgement.